# Change background color of items in gridview on touch

Tags: android, gridview, ontouchlistener

I have a gridView layout which is populated with textView elements.  I have a onTouch() implementation for gridView where the cells that are touched upon need to change background color.  Below is my code, but it doesn't work and the VM shuts down when I do the touch.

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

            int action = me.getActionMasked();
            float currentXPosition = me.getX();
            float currentYPosition = me.getY();
            int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);

            // Change the color of the key pressed
            ((TextView) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            return true;
    }
}
```

Edit: Logcat trace

```
12-10 15:34:28.081: E/InputEventReceiver(829): Exception dispatching input event.
12-10 15:34:28.081: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at com.example.helloworld.GridViewActivity$1.onTouch(GridViewActivity.java:62)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4134)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4226)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-10 15:34:28.221: E/MessageQueue-JNI(829):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 15:34:28.263: D/AndroidRuntime(829): Shutting down VM
12-10 15:34:28.263: W/dalvikvm(829): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.example.helloworld.GridViewActivity$1.onTouch(GridViewActivity.java:62)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7122)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1877)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4134)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4226)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-10 15:34:28.362: E/AndroidRuntime(829):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you provide a logcat trace?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I figured it out!

I was typecasting a TextView on the wrong return type here

```
((TextView) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

What I really needed was the method getChildAt and not getItemAtPosition (which returns a String)

```
String s = (String) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position);
TextView tv = (TextView) gridView.getChildAt(position);
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: `getChildAt` position is not same as items position. You will get errros and wrong views.

Answer (score 0):

use `gridView.setOnItemClickListener` instead. you will also get the position in the `onItemClick` method and won't have to calculate it like you do now.

**edit**
i just realized you want to change the color while the item is still pressed. in that case i would suggest to set the background of the items in the adapter to a selector drawable

Comment: Actually, the color should remain "selected" until I unselect with a different button.  So, a selector would not work.  Also, I want to actually touch-drag across multiple items rather than click on one.  So, if I touch-drag across 3 cells, the color of those 3 cells should change to Red.

Comment: a selector will be perfect for you! you will have to make the background red when pressed OR selected. and in the onItemClick function set the current item to selected.

Comment: Actually, changing the color when selected is just the initial stage.  I need to perform more operations that do not involve color.  So, I just need a way to access the TextView item when it is touched.

Comment: in that case i would add a touch listener to each item in the grid through the grid adapter.